# Launch sbt run with a specific port number

Tags: sbt

I would like to launch sbt with a specific port number directly :

```
 sbt run 9001
```

does not work as 9001 is ignored.

What works however is to first launch `sbt` and then use the command `run 9001`

How could I combine both directly in one command line I could run in my shell ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I remember well, I think you have to add all the parameters between quotes. In you case:

```
sbt "run 9001"
```

Comment: As a finatra user, I had also to add the following line to my server definition:
`override val defaultFinatraHttpPort: String = ":9001"` as pointed out [here](https://twitter.github.io/finatra/user-guide/http/server.html#flags)

Answer (score 2):

When you run `sbt` console it's enough to use `run 9001` without any quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IntelliJ and using inbuild SBT Shell, then you can use the below command

```
run 8080
```

The server will be started in the mentioned port 8080

[image]

Comment: If still you cannot able to change the port, then just restart the sbt shell. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

When I set up the configuration on IntelliJ, I had to add quote.[image]